# cant remove file {HOME}/ as shell recognises the name as a directory

Tags: shell

I'm new to shell scripting and using github and I have an issue where I accidentally created this file called `{HOME}/'

I tried removing this file by using the command rm {HOME}/
However, I get the response 
    rm: cannot remove `{HOME}/': Is a directory

This is the whole response I get when doing git status:

```
**# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   {HOME}/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to    track)**
```

How can I remove this file without adding it as tracked and pushing it to master branch?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`{HOME}/` is a directory, not a file, as a `/` is not a valid character in a filename.

The fact that it is showing up in `git status` indicates that the directory is not empty.

Once you are sure that there is nothing important in the directory, you can remove it using:

```
rm -r {HOME}
```